# SELECT SUM inside looping

Tags: php, sql, loops

I have this looping and i want the total is the fucntion sum of each looping.

```
<?php foreach ($siswa as $rows) {
    echo"<tr>
        <td>$rows->nis</td>
        <td>$rows->nama</td>
        <td>total</td></tr>";
        }?>
```

i can generate this sql only for one row, how can i make this for looping?

```
$total= SELECT  CEIL(SUM((((ulangan_1 + ulangan_2 + ulangan_3 + ulangan_4)/4)*50/100)+(uts*30/100)+(uas*20/100))) as total_nilai 
                  FROM tbl_nilai 
                  WHERE nis='$nis'
```

Comment: Nested aggregation? Like `select sum(total_nilai) from (SELECT nis, CEIL(SUM((((ulangan_1 + ulangan_2 + ulangan_3 + ulangan_4)/4)*50/100)+(uts*30/100)+(uas*20/100))) as total_nilai 
                  FROM tbl_nilai group by nis) dt`

Comment: The output doesn't what I want

Comment: Well, *you* know what you want, I don't :-) it was just a guess